# Fix double hyphen in tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I noticed there was a tag with two consecutive hyphens, [eloquent--relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eloquent--relationship), which essentially functions as a combination of the tags [laravel-eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-eloquent)/[eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eloquent) and [relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/relationship). This tag should only have one space.

I searched to see if any other tags had a double hyphen and found [jenkins--x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jenkins--x) which should also have only one hyphen to represent the space in the name (see [their website](https://jenkins-x.io/)).

Can both of these tags be renamed to only have one hyphen?

Comment: Yeah, there's no good reason to have those with an obvious typo. Fixed